# Potential energies and Directions of angular momentums of an electron in $\rm H$ atom

Tags: magnetic-fields, atomic-physics, potential-energy, magnetic-moment

I know in a Hydrogen atom, the electron revolves around the nucleus (proton) in a circular path. In addition, the electron spins about its own axis. Due to this spin, electron has a magnetic dipole moment (U) in a direction opposite to its spin angular momentum. As seen from the frame of reference of electron , the electron itself is only spinning but the proton is moving around it in  a circular path with the same speed and radius as electron in ground frame, This motion of proton around electron produces a magnetic field $B$.

Now I saw these 2 lines below in the *MTG Physics for Today* monthly magazine October 2021 edition that,

> '*This magnetic field and magnetic dipole moment of electron have
> mutual potential energy.*'.

1. Could someone explain the meaning of this statement. And if possible mathematically too.

Another line from the same magazine:

> *If angular momentum L of electron and its spin angular momentum S are parallel, the potential energy is different from the case when they are anti parallel.*

Now

1. Why is the Potential energy different? (Please show mathematically if possible)
2. Incase if they are anti parallel what what would be the direction of magnetic moment be parallel with?

Comment: *the electron revolves around the nucleus (proton) in a circular path* This model is about 100 years out-of-date.

Comment: @Ghoster let it be brother :) im studying in high school and learning modern physics so thats why knowing this would boost my knowledge on this topic which is a part of my curriculum. Please do help me if you do know. Regards

Comment: [Magnetic potential energy](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/magpot.html)

Comment: The Bohr model  should interest you http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/bohrcn.html

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr_model

Comment: @annav I think the OP probably understands the Bohr model, but is/was unclear on how magnetic dipoles interact with external magnetic fields. This is normally part of a course covering classical electromagnetism.

Comment: @Ghoster exactly thats what i mean

Comment: The magnetic dipole moment can be derived by considering the atom as a circular loop of current, then you can find magnetic potential energy from that